# How to stop chrome/firefox downloading a gif?

Tags: browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, animated-gif

When I visit any page containing some animated `gif`s (Google+, 9gag etc), all those seem to start loading. My bandwidth is limited and I don't want those to be downloaded unless I really want to view. I have seen some plugins which just stop *animation* but the image itself is *downloaded* anyway. 9gag.com had initially this feature which just showed a static image (if it is an animated gif) and started downloading only after I clicked on it (they have removed it now).

So, is there any plugin which can stop *downloading* gif? Or, do I need to write an extension? Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you don’t want to block *all* images right? The problem with this is that it would be simple enough to block all `.gif` files, but if you want to block *only animated* `.gif` files, then the extension would still have to download any `.gif` files embedded in the page to determine if they are animated or not. Your best bet is to block all GIFs. (I just thought of an idea that might work well, but I don’t think it has been done. If I get some time, I’ll try to whip up something in case nobody knows of an existing solution.)

Comment: Blocking all gif will do. All other images should be visible. I googled, but it seems everybody is concerned about the _distraction_ of animation. So, most of the plugins just stop the animation. I could write a chrome extension; but I was just wondering if any other solution exists.

Comment: Since animated GIFs are often several megabytes, I agree that they can be quite a nuisance, especially when there’re several in a page (you could practically create a DoS with a page loaded with giant animated GIFs). The few [image-blocking extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/block%20images) I can find tend to be the block-all-images kind. There is however [*Safe Blocker*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/safebrowser/bohffanknhdkpedmpcgephfdgabemfkb/details) which has an optional GIF-blocking function. I can’t test it at the moment, but it looks promising.

Comment: Just tried _Safe Blocker_. It just gives you a proxy site which is definitely not what I want.

Comment: Ah, shame. They [didn’t mention that](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/safebrowser/bohffanknhdkpedmpcgephfdgabemfkb/details), but it would explain the [review saying it’s slow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/safebrowser/bohffanknhdkpedmpcgephfdgabemfkb/reviews). It’s strange that this hasn’t been solved already. Perhaps it’s because pages full of animated GIFs are still fairly new, so it hasn’t been addressed yet. Try this [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/164679). It didn’t work in an old version of Chromium, but it may work in newer versions of Chrome.

Comment: Tried in chrome. Error: `$ is not defined`. Seems `@require` is not allowed in chrome. Also, I think the script will not be able to stop  downloading ajax `gif`s which get added as you scroll down.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that you have to use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) to use such userscripts. Uninstall the script, install Tampermonkey, go to the script page and the `[Install]` button should be different; it should have a Tampermonkey icon. Now it will support the more advanced GreaseMonkey stuff that Chrome’s native userscript support doesn’t. And no, I don’t think that script supports dynamic blocking; it looks like it only runs once on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not got any suitable extension/plugin yet. I have tried using the following user-script with [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) in Chrome. It is working great. Blocking all gifs (including ajax gifs) in site 9gag.com. For some reason, ajax gifs in google+ dont get blocked (investigating that). Many thanks to [Synetec](https://superuser.com/users/3279/synetech) for his help, effort and code. Here is the user-script (most of the scripts are copied from [Synetec's userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/164679)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       gifBlock
// @namespace  http://i.have.no.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Stops downloading gif images (including ajax gifs) in 9gag.com (or any page if you just fix the @match rule)
// @match      http://*.9gag.com
// @copyright  2012+, Nobody
// ==/UserScript==

function tamperMonkeyWrap()
{   
    function log(m)
    {
        console.log(m);
    }
    function jQWrap($)
    {
        log("Extension execution begins...");

        function blockGifs()
        {        
            $('img').each(function() {
                var $img = $(this),
                    src = $img.attr('src'),
                    w = $img.width(),
                    h = $img.height(),
                    cursor = $img.css('cursor'),
                    parts = src.split('.'),
                    ext = parts[parts.length-1];

                if ($.trim(ext.toLowerCase()) != "gif")
                    return;            

                $img.attr('data-imgurl', src);
                $img.data('cursor', cursor);
                $img.css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $img.addClass('gif-blocked');                
                h = h > 100? h : 100;
                $img.attr('src', '//ipsumimage.appspot.com/'+w+'x'+h+'?l=Gif (Click)');
            }); 
        }

        function interceptAjax () {
            $('body').ajaxComplete(
                function (event, requestData)
                {
                    log("Blocking GIF [Ajax] ...");                
                    blockGifs();
                }
            );
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            log("Blocking GIF [Ready]....");
            blockGifs();
            interceptAjax();        
            $(document).on('click', 'img.gif-blocked', function(ev) {            
                var $img = $(this),
                    url = $img.attr('data-imgurl'),
                    cursor = $img.data('cursor');

                $img.attr('src', url);
                $img.css('cursor', cursor);
                $img.removeClass('gif-blocked');
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });  
        });

        log("Document is not ready yet. trying block just in case it takes time to be _ready_ (google+).");
        blockGifs();
    }

    if (window.jQuery == undefined)
    {
        log("Loading jQuery...");
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
        scriptTag.onload = function(){
            log("jQuery loaded.");
            window.jQuery = jQuery; 
            jQWrap(jQuery);
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
    }
    else
    {
        log("jQuery already included in the page");
        jQWrap(window.jQuery);
    }   
}

var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.text = '(' + tamperMonkeyWrap.toString() + ')();';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Now:

1. Install TamperMonkey
2. Go to dashboard
3. Click on 'new script'
4. Paste the above code
5. Save and see if it works. (works only on 9gag.com now. But you can change the `@match` directive to match any site you want. use `@match http://*/*` to work for all sites (http). Change to `https` for any secured http site, e.g. google+)

Comment: To bad that quite a few users have started to upload GIFs with .jpg extension. So called *animated JPEGs*. Presumably this idiocy stated because some sites would not allow uploading GIFs but checked only the extension to determine the file type. Same way you do it. My guess is that `if ($.trim(ext.toLowerCase()) != "gif")` will catch only half the GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

Some nice firefox addons:

adblock - intelligent blocking of ads

flashblock - all flash will be blocked until you doesn't click them

imgblock - blocks ALL images, everywhere (can be with a click temporarily disabled)

ghostery - blocks the social networking sites (they can make more hundred kbyte per page visit!)

Comment: I know about these. But those dont do what I want. i.e. stop downloading (not just make it invisible) just gif images.